# Screen -X isn't working ("No screen found")

Tags: php, bash

I have this php code:

```
echo shell_exec('sh /backups/turnon.sh');
```

The `/backups/turnon.sh` code is:

> screen -X 'cd /ftb; java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -jar mcpc.jar'

However, that outputs to the website:

> No screen session found.

However if I open PuTTY and I do `screen -x` I can load the screen with no issue. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Presumably the PHP code is being run by Apache, while `screen` runs as your login account (ie, not apache).

Comment: Hm, is there a way to force it to run as root? Or to make a screen work on any account? There's only one ever running at once.

Comment: You could use `sudo` or put the setuid bit on your .sh, but that could be a bad idea security wise.

Comment: It's ok, the point of the bash file is to be run by anyone (it executes it when you click a button, it's to make sure people can put the server back up). Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Like @FlorentBayle said, start screen like `sudo -u apache screen` ?

Comment: @Bishop does that work with `sudo -u root screen -X...`?

Comment: Off hand, I would think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why one would do this, but as a sample of *one way* to do it.

---

### www-data

One way to solve this case would be to attach to correct user session. For Apache that is normally *`www-data`* which is a user with stripped down privileges. Use `ps` on *apache* or,

in PHP you can run this to show you which user PHP (Apache) run as:

```
<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>
```

Output:

```
www-data
```

Note that if you run the script using PHP from command-line you will get current user, which you do not want.

---

### Initiate screen session for www-data

*www-data* is normally not set up with password, as such we cannot log in with that user. To run a screen session for *www-data* one can do the following:

```
$ sudo su - www-data
$ script /dev/null
$ screen
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
sudo su - www-data -c 'script -c screen /dev/null'
```

This will start a new shell in *www-data*'s home directory, typically `/var/www/`. The *script* command is one way to prevent access error to terminal when running *screen* due to the use of `sudo su`.

---

### Execute script from PHP

Now that we have a *screen* session for *www-data* we can continue with the Bash script.

```
/usr/bin/screen -X stuff '/usr/bin/java -cp /some/path/ Test

'
```

and execute it from PHP.

---

### Capturing output

If you want the buffer from screen in PHP there is various ways:

First create a log-file for *www-data*'s screen session.

```
touch /tmp/www-data-scr.log
chown www-data:www-data /tmp/www-data-scr.log
```

- Use `logfile` option in `.screenrc` and run *screen* with `-L`.
- Run `script -f /tmp/www-data-scr.log` inside screen.
- Start *www-data* script screen session with log-file, `-f` to flush.

  ```
    sudo su - www-data -c 'script -fc screen /tmp/www-data-scr.log'
  ```
- Copy buffer to file to get a snapshot.

  ```
    /usr/bin/screen -X hardcopy /tmp/www-data-scr.log
  ```
- etc.

You would typically add a

```
sleep N
```

in your bash script after issuing the command producing some output and before reading the log file.

---

### To sum up

As privileged user:

```
touch /tmp/screen.log
sudo chown www-data:www-data /tmp/screen.log
sudo su - www-data -c 'script -c screen /dev/null'
```

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/screen -X stuff 'java -cp /some/class/path/ Test

'
sleep 1
/usr/bin/screen -X hardcopy /tmp/screen.log
sed '/^$/d' /tmp/screen.log
```

PHP:

```
<pre>
<?php
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
echo htmlentities(shell_exec('sh /path/to/script'));
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

The man page for `screen` specifically states:

```
-x   Attach to a not detached screen session. (Multi display mode).
-X   Send the specified command to a running screen session.
```

The error message you're getting says that there's no existing `screen` process running to attach to. Something is different between your PuTTY login environment and the environment in which the script is trying to run, possibly that you have a `screen` session running as your PuTTY login user but none running as the user running the script.