# Running a java command with a bash file

Tags: java, bash, debian, putty

I am running a bash file through PuTTY. This is the contents of it:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -X 'java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -jar mcpc.jar'
screen -x
```

When I run `/backups/turnon.sh`, it successfully connects to the screen however the java command is never run. Running the java command through PuTTY works fine. The bash file doesn't break at any point (as `screen -x` works fine), what's wrong?

Comment: You probably are trying to use both these questions (this one and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263204/screen-x-isnt-working-no-screen-found)) to debug the same issue, but please wait until one is answered before asking the other.

Comment: @kojiro The other one was answered in the comments. I'm using them to solve two different issues with the same program.

Comment: How do you know 1. it successfully connects to the screen session and 2. the java command never runs?

Comment: [Send commands to a GNU screen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6065178/3278057)

Comment: @Kojiro 1) Because I can use screen -x, and if it doesn't it sends `No screen session found.`. 2) Because when I enter the screen the output isn't there and the result of the java command doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not already, read the answer provided by Gilles here:

- [Send commands to a GNU screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6065178/3278057)

In short (to make some redundancy) the `-X` option expects a command. That is: a [`screen`-command](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Command-Summary), not a shell/system command.

You could use the [stuff](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Paste)-command. I.e.:

```
screen -X stuff 'java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -jar mcpc.jar

'
```

If you omit the *command* the target screen should respond with an error like:

> -X: unknown command 'java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -jar mcpc.jar'

in the running screen window.

---

Notes:

- At least here, I have to use double new-line at end of command. (Like example above).
- As an alternative you can add the control character `^M`, typically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> in Vim, bash etc. That inserts `<CR>`, byte `0x0d`.
- `mcpc.jar` must be in local path or provided by full/relative path.