# Executing Bash script from PHP but nothing happens

Tags: php, linux, bash, webserver

I know that this question has been discussed before but i still can't find a solution. I'm trying to execute a Bash script from a PHP file on a (really small) website which is run using the PHP built in webserver. When running the PHP file in the terminal with

php -f test.php

it works fine and the bash script executes. However when i start the webserver and call the PHP function from the website, nothing happens. The Bash script is invoked with:

exec('/home/user/website/bash_script', $out, $return);

inside the PHP-file and i get that return = 1.
On the website the PHP script that executes the bash-script is called by another PHP script through:

`<input type="button" value="..." onclick="location='test.php'"/>`

I first thought that it was a problem with my permissions, but i added the script-file in visudo to be able to run it as super-user without password but still no luck. I also changed the file permissions to 755.
Here is test.php (which works fine when run through the terminal):

```
<?php
        exec ('/home/user/website/test');
?>
```

Also i CAN execute exec('cp bla bla2'); from the webserver so theres no problem with exec()

EDIT------------------------------------------------------------------------

The Bash script is sending a command to a different screen and it seems that this is the root of the problem. I think that this can solve my problem:
[Screen -X isn't working ("No screen found")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263204/screen-x-isnt-working-no-screen-found)

Comment: Maybe a user issue. on web you are 'www-data' on shell mostly 'root', test it `print \`whoami\`;`

Comment: I ran exec('whoami') and it says my username, so this should not be a problem right?

Comment: On both, web and shell?

Comment: Just tried it again and since i changed all permissions it now says 'root' on both web and shell

Comment: @user1621127 Have you tried like this: `exec('sh /home/user/website/test');`?

Comment: Please try all the suggestions from @PaulCrovella's link. The part about `2>&1` is especially important as otherwise all the important error messages are lost

Comment: This is the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263204/screen-x-isnt-working-no-screen-found